# ip range and subnet mask

Tags: ip, range, subnet

I have:
ip range,
subnet mask.

I need to assign ip addresses for devices in subnets (there are five of them and they are with different number of hosts in each of them).
So for instance ip range is 192.168.244.0 - 192.168.245.555 and mask /27.
Is first value of the given range(192.168.244.0) is network ip or i need to find it in another way? Because if i take 192.168.244.0/27 there are not enough space for all hosts. Also task says to use given mask for all the five subnets, so i do not understand if 27 is the network mask or mask of subnets. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The range 192.168.244.0 - 192.168.245.2(?)55 has got a /23 mask.

They begin to differ in the third octet in the least significant bit. 8 bits in each of the first two octets plus 7 in the third is 23. The network address is 192.168.244.0/23 (all host bits zero).

Check [this great answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7106/how-do-you-calculate-the-prefix-network-subnet-and-host-numbers) on NESE for subnet calculations.